# Download canvas.todataurl via window.location (How to change filename?)

Tags: javascript

I create a jpeg file over canvas. The image is downloaded and has the name "Download" without file extension. How can I modify the file name for the download via the script?

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("rankingTable")).then(function (canvas) {
  var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1)
    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  
  window.location.href=image;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the filename in the download attribute:

```
    function downloadData(linkData, filename) {
      let link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = linkData;
      link.download = filename;
      let target = document.body;
      target.appendChild(link);  // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
      link.click();              // simulate click
      target.removeChild(link);  // remove the link when done
    }
```

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

I am not sure you need to replace the "image/png" with "image/octet-stream", so try this code:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("rankingTable")).then(function (canvas) {
  var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
  downloadData(image, "ranking-table.png");
});
```